# Is it possible to save the state of movable divs with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, positioning

So I have a page with divs which I can drag. Is it possible - without JSON or database access to save positions of these divs so that when I open the page next time they are in the same place as I left them? This is a local file so I CAN write to the file - if that is at all a consideration.

Comment: Is using cookies an option? Alternatively, what browser? More modern browsers support offline storage that can be used.

Comment: I am targeting any modern browsers / Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari. Yes, it will be a local page so offline storage is an option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading this question/answer to learn how to get the position of a div with JavaScript: [Get the position of a div/span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag).

After that, simply use JavaScript to persist the data in a cookie. Here's [a decent tutorial](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) to get you started on that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using cookies to store the information.  IT would allow a means to save the window properties, and not reach back server side.

**SET COOKIE**

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
   var exdate=new Date();
   exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
   var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
   document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

**GET COOKIE**

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

**CHECK COOKIE**

```
function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post your references when copying and pasting code from external sources. For example, this code comes from the site who's name shouldn't be spoken: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp. See also: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: oops, yeah sorry forgot reference to the site that shouldn't be spoken.

Comment: Why the name of the site that should not be spoken?