# javascript: moving an image

Tags: javascript

**editing this page for those who want to read this in the future :P**

seems i'm asking too much here.. but thanks a lot for those who helps me with this problem ! actually i want to accept all of your answer, but it seems i only can accept one.. >.>

**Question 1:**
i want to move an image, but when i try to get the image position(using `document.getElementById().style.left`), it shows me a *NaN value* when i convert it to integer. i wonder how to fix this :/

here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function playit()
    {
        alert(parseInt(document.getElementById('ball').style.left)); <!-- shows a NaN value -->
    }
</script>
```

i put the image into table and call it using onclick function; `<td id="frame" colspan="5" onclick="playit()">` to be exact and i declared the image like this: `<img src="play/ball.png" id="ball" name="ball"/>`

here's my CSS for the picture:

```
#ball
{
    position:absolute;
    top:500px;
    left:500px; 
}
```

**SOLUTION(given by [VIPIN JAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1128293/vipin-jain)):** use `.offsetLeft` instead of `element.style.left`

**Question 2:** 
**EDIT:**
i fixed it with `.offsetLeft` and it works just fine. now when i'm trying to move the image, i got another error. It's said that i'm using *too much recursion*. I know it happens because i'm using a recursion, but i wonder, what's wrong with using recursion?

here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var lball = document.getElementById('ball').offsetLeft;
    var speed = 500;

    function moveleft()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('ball').offsetLeft >0)
        {
            document.getElementById('ball').offsetLeft-=1;

            setTimeout(moveleft(), speed);
        }
        else gameover();
    }
    function playit()
    {
        score = 0;
        setTimeout(moveleft(), speed);
    }
</script>
```

can someone help me with this? thanks :)

**SOLUTION(given by [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu)):** *please refer to [Teemu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173310/1334588) below on '**Edit II**' part.*

**Question 3(actually i'm asking it on the comments :P)** 
when i tried to set the image position using `document.getElementById('ball').offsetLeft-=1;`, it shows an *undefined value*.

**SOLUTION(given by [Kemal Fadillah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732470/kemal-fadillah)):** "That's because you can't set the `offsetLeft` value of an element. You have to set the new position value to `.style.left`. Something like this: `element.style.left = new_value + "px";`"

**Question 4(again, i'm asking it on the comments :P)** 
it seems that *the image won't move smoothly*(it looks like it is suddenly "warps" to another place). i have raised the `speed` value but it still not working. am i missing something with it? i wonder.. :/ 

**SOLUTION(given by [Kemal Fadillah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732470/kemal-fadillah)):** "Set `speed` to 10 or 20. That should make the animation smooth enough. To make the image moves faster, instead of decreasing the left offset by 1, try to decrease it by 3."

Comment: If the CSS property `left` is not set, `document.getElementById('ball').style.left` will return an empty string. And if you pass an empty string to `parseInt()` it will give you `NaN`.

Comment: @KemalFadillah i have using it on the CSS. here's my CSS for the ball:
#ball
{
 position:absolute;
 top:500px;
 left:500px; 
}

Comment: @KemalFadillah This might be a cross-browser issue. IE humbly gives me all style values defined in external stylesheets too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('ball').style.left` returns `''` (or `undefined`), if you haven't set the property before retrieving it. That's why you get `NaN` from `parseInt()`.

**Edit:**

Seems you're style definition is OK (after you edited your post). You can try to use the radix in the `parseInt()`:

```
alert(parseInt(document.getElementById('ball').style.left,10));
```

This is documentated as not oblique, but using it sometimes helps.

**Edit II**

This happens, because you're executing all `setTimeout`s twice, and you're not clearing them. Try it this way:

```
var delay;

function moveLeft(){
  :
  if(delay){ // Add this if before all of your setTimeout() calls and in gameover() too
    clearTimeout(delay);
  }
  delay=setTimeout(moveLeft, speed);
  :
}
```

By setting timeout like this `setTimeout(doFunction(),delaytime);` executes `doFunction` rightaway because of `()`, and again after `delaytime`, that really is too much of recursion...

Comment: i have tried it and it's not working either; it still shows a NaN value. i wonder what radix means anyway :/

Comment: @aquatorrent I'm not sure if I can explain this in english, but... When you use `16` as a radix, you'll get a hex-value, if you'll use `2` as a radix you'll get a binary value etc. For example: `parseInt('100',2)` returns `4`, as `parseInt('100',10)` returns `100`.

Comment: oh, so it's like converting the integer to another type of integer?

Comment: @aquatorrent Yes, that's the purpose. Did you got your code to work? If you didn't, please use `offsetLeft` instead of `style.left` like VIPIN JAN has proposed.

Comment: oh, i didn't notice the link before XD i have checked it and i confused about the `el` . what type is it?  is it the same type as `document.getElementById` ?

Comment: @aquatorrent Hard to say without the code, there is no `XD` or `el` in the code you posted. Please add the whole (relevant) code to your question. At least the `head`-part of the HTML, and all script&HTML dealing with your problem. This seems to be more like issue of timing or scope.

Comment: i have edited it and it works! :D but i got another error with recursion..  i have updated my code though :D

Comment: thanks for the code, it's working! ^^ now i know that i have to use cleartimeout first before setting another timeout :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery, it's much easier. Try something like

```
$(function(){
$("img#ball").offset({top: 10px, left: 500px});
});
```

More information can be found here:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

information about jQuery in general can be found here:

http://jquery.com/

Comment: i haven't learned jQuery yet and i have been told to do it with javascript.. :(

Comment: You have to start somewhere, this could be your chance! And jQuery is also javascript so that should not be the problem :-)

Comment: oh, really? maybe i'll try to do it as soon as i finished this with javascript then :D

Answer (score 1):

This requires `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` values please refer to the link

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288708/1128293)

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the CSS styling by using `element.style` if it's declared inside an external stylesheet.
From MDN Documentation:

> However, it is not useful for learning about the element's style in
>   general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the
>   element's inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules
>   elsewhere, such as style rules in the  section, or external
>   style sheets.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style

Instead, you'll have to use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) to get the properties.

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('ball')).left; // returns 500px
```

Comment: thanks, it works! now i'm trying to set the value to a variable. but it doesn't work. can't i use parseInt() to parse it? here's how i do it: var ball = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('ball')));

Comment: you forgot `.left` at the end of the `window.getComputedStyle()` call.

Comment: i add `.left` as you said earlier, but it gives me an undefined value. is it like this? `var lball = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('ball')).left);`

Comment: Is the page hosted on a live server so I can see it? Or perhaps you can post a JsFiddle instead?

Comment: it's not hosted on a live server.. and what is JsFiddle? i just learned to code javascript some day ago and have no clue about lots of things.. sorry >.>

Comment: @aquatorrent Nevermind then. Can you tell which part is returning undefined? To my knowledge, `parseInt()` only returns either an integer or `NaN` and not `undefined`.

Comment: first, i declare this: `var lball = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('ball')).left);` then in `playit` function i'm using this: `alert(lball);`

Comment: Can you update the question and add the updated code? There might be some issue with scoping.

Comment: i just change it with `.offsetleft` and it works! but it seems i got another error.. and i have updated the code :)

Comment: That's because you can't set the `offsetLeft` value of an element. You have to set the new position value to `.style.left`. Something like this: `element.style.left = new_value + "px";`.

Comment: oh i see. i have changed it but i got another problem. it seems that it won't move smoothly(it looks like the picture is suddenly "Warps" to another place). i have raised the speed value but it still not working. am i missing something with it? i wonder.. :/

Comment: Set `speed` to 10 or 20. That should make the animation smooth enough. To make the image moves faster, instead of decreasing the left offset by 1, try to decrease it by 3.