# CSS default style of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements)

Is there a reference somewhere of all the default styles of DOM elements?

For example, how big the margin above an `<h1>` is?

Is there some easy way to extract this? I tried:

```
document.getElementById("myheading").style.marginTop
```

But it returned blank. Presumably because nothing had been defined for `marginTop`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is provided by w3 for CSS 2.1: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey ...which is not the most recent version of the HTML specification.

Comment: @Matt - CSS 2.1 is the most recent official version of CSS. I edited my verbiage so that people that don't bother clicking the link don't complain.

Comment: "Official," perhaps, but what the _de facto_ current version (CSS3)?

Comment: @Matt - appreciate the unnecessary argumentation. Despite my huge advocacy of CSS3, I'm not deluded enough to think that its been standardized in any way, other than polite suggestions (thats why you use all those silly prefixes ... no one has agreed on anything). I provided that reference because it is useful for things like h1, the item he refers to.

Comment: Are you actually trying to get the top margin of the element? Or perhaps a different value? Like the position of an element related to its offset parent? Or to the document? Maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag

Comment: It's important to remember that these things can be defined in a **user agent stylesheet**. Those for main browsers can be found via [**this excellent answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6867287/1615483)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. The specs have a loosely defined list. [HTML4](http://w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints)

If you wish to actually see the computed style, you can use a program like Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, IE Developer Tools, or Opera Dragonfly.

If you need to programmatically get the computed style, I recommend that you use jquery to even out the differences, or use the getComputedStyle() or currentStyle attributes of an element. jQuery does this for you automatically.

If you just want to know how to handle this cross-browser without going insane, I recommend using a Reset Stylesheet. There are many. Eric Meyer's is the most famous, but nowadays there are many tools, like Bootstrap, Blueprint, Normalize, and YUI.

Comment: Reset is a good one, but a better one (IMHO) is Normalize.css. It doesn't seek to take it back to scratch like Reset, it tries to create a similar experience across all browsers by eliminating the quirks of individual ones.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser has it's own implementation in it's **user agent stylesheet**. [This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867287/1615483) has links to resources for WebKit, Firefox/Gecko and IE. You can discover the values on a (rendered) DOM node using [`window.getComputedStyle(node);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle). Note that there are some exceptions to this method (visited links will return as if not visited for security reasons).

For `<h1>`, here is the relevant CSS for each

[**Webkit**](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#L164)

```
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67__qem;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0;
-webkit-margin-end: 0;
font-weight: bold
```

[**Firefox/Gecko**](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css)

```
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: .67em 0;
```

[**IE6/7**](http://www.iecss.com/)

```
display: block;
font-size: 24pt;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 14pt 0;
```

**IE8/9**

```
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0.67em 0;
page-break-after: avoid;
```