# Is there a way to use JavaScript to impose top and left property values on html spans?

Tags: html, dom

The very informative S.O. question

```
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag"
```

notes ways to find the position, but if *top* and *left* are "invalid properties* for the span element, how does one position it to the pixel, exactimento! where one desires?

Comment: make sure it is set to display as a block level element with a position that makes use of those properties. Like absolute, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the positioning used by html css are :
static
fixed
relative
absolute
top bottom right and left can be used if the position is relative, absolute or fixed..
for example:

```
<div id="main">
<span id="pos_fixed"></span>
</div>
then you can have:
#main  {
position:relative;
}
span#pos_fixed
{
position:fixed;
top:30px;
right:5px;
}
```

but these wont work if they are static.
you an read more at: http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm

Comment: Your answer confirmed that what I had been attempting was possible, and I discovered that my error had been having a *left:12px* statement in the CSS declaration for the span id, and another, different value, *left:37px;* in a class I had set for that span.  So in the Chrome Inspecter I was seeing the message about an invalid property and misunderstood.  Thought span could not have those properties, duh~OH.  Got it all sorted now.