# firefox returning 0 for this.x and this.y in jquery hover

Tags: firefox, coordinates

Using a hover function on a set of elements:

```
   $('.thumb-Image').hover(function () {
        alert(this.x);
```

This works fine in Chrome but Firefox (22)...both x and y are 0.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I should not be using this.x and this.y ..it was also returning undefined in IE.

So instead I used Jens Fransden's getTop and getLeft answer at the bottom of this post:
[Get the position of a div/span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag)

This gets me exactly what I need in ff and ie as well as Chrome