# How to get coordinates of the draggable image from a div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a small `div` (`overflow:hidden`) in which I'm showing a big image which is draggable.
I want to crop the Image in the exact position in which it is visible in the `div`.

NOTE: I know I can use **html2canvas**, but I want to crop the Image in its original size.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle or something... need more specifics

Answer (score 1):

See this link to get the position of a DOM element:
[Get the position of a div/span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag)

It sounds like you'll need to get the position of several different elements to calculate the relative coordinates you want.

Comment: We'd need a clearer picture/description of what you're trying to do to give more specific guidance.