# JS/HTML dropdown menu in MS word style(pic in the post)

Tags: javascript, html

So i would like to create a dropdown menu like this(with thumbnails). I have 5 html elements that i would like to show in that style. I added my code but i have no idea how to make a dropdown menu in that style.

[image: MS Word]

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){

      var c=document.getElementById("leplanner-canvas");
      var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, c.height/2);
      ctx.lineTo(c.width, c.height/2);
      ctx.stroke();

    for(var i =0; i< document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i++){
     var box = ".box-"+i;
        console.log(i);
        $(box).draggable({
          grid: [ 72, 12 ],
          stop: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('dragstart');
          },
          stop: function( event, ui ) {

            var json = [];

            for(var i =0; i< document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i++){

              var b = {
                x: document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i].offsetLeft,
                y: document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i].offsetTop
                /// see asendada koordinaatidega võrreldes canvasega + juurde veel laius ja muu
                ////http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag
              }

              json.push(b);

            }

            //See on see mis ab'i siis läheb
            document.getElementsByClassName('json')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
          },
          drag: function( event, ui ) {
            //http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag
            // siin või jquery ui kaudu tuleks kontrollida, et ei saaks kaste üksteise peale panna
          }

        });

        $(box).resizable({
          grid: [ 72, 12 ]
        });
    }


    }


  </script>
```

```css
body,html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
   position: center;
    }

    .box {
      height: 71px;
      width: 71px;
      margin: 5px;
   border: 1px solid gray;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #fff;
      z-index: 20;
   display: inline-block;
    }
 
    #leplanner-canvas {
      background-color: lightgray;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -480px;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .list {
 padding-left:450px;
    margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 190px;
 position: float-right:
    height: 100px;
    width: 10%:
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>LePlanner</title>
  <style media="screen">

    

  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="box box-0">
      Tekst
    </div>
 <div class="box box-1">
      Youtube
    </div>
 <div class="box box-2">
      Twitter
    </div>
 <div class="box box-3">
      Facebook
    </div>
 <div class="box box-4">
      Google
    </div>
 <div class="box box-5">
      Meetod
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="leplanner-canvas" width="960" height="400"></canvas>
  <div class="json"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's div with fixed dimensions and custom made scroll functionality.

Example:

```css
.menu {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 52px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.nav:hover {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
  <div class="nav">MENU</div>
</div>
```