# how to reset position (0,0) after dragging and item from a parent to an other parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

So I'm trying to drag and element from a `div` into an other `div`. The problem is that I can't get the right position to drop the new element in it's new parent. While dragging I can get the position but it come in negative.

I have tried to append the new element in the new `div` the instant it enters the area using `dragenter` event, but it didn't solve the problem. Are there any idea's? Here is a screenshot from the console.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRFFC.png): [chrome console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRFFC.png)

Comment: Don't really understand the "the wite position to drop"... Any code you can show us?

Comment: `function drag_start(event) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",
    (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"),10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - event.clientY));
} 
function drag_over(event) { 
 event.preventDefault(); 
 mod=document.getElementsByName('module');
    var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');

    CX= (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10));
    CY= (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10));
` this is the code that gets the positions

Comment: Instead of getting the computed CSS left, get the offset position: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag