# How to get updated top position of scrolled up div?

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent, css-position

**http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/YNBgqE**

After you scroll the `#tickers-col` how do you get the correct updated top position of the div?

From the log no matter how far up the column goes, it still displays the original `y` position of the div:

[image]
`colPos Object {x: 8, y: 8}`

```js
const tickersCol = document.getElementById("tickers-col");


// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag
function getPos(el) {
  for (var lx=0, ly=0;
       el != null;
       lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.offsetTop, el = el.offsetParent);
  return {x: lx,y: ly};
}

function mouseHover() {
  const colPos = getPos(tickersCol);
  console.log('colPos', colPos)
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#tickers-col {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 120px;
  color: white;
  background: salmon;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="tickers-col">
  <ul>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">aaa</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">bbb</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ccc</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ddd</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">eee</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">fff</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ggg</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">hhh</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">iii</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">jjj</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">kkk</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">lll</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">mmm</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">nnn</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ooo</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ppp</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">qqq</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">rrr</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">sss</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ttt</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">uuu</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">vvv</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">www</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">yyy</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">xxx</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">zzz</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Found the `getPos` function from here: [Get the position of a div/span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I really don't understand what exactly you are trying to do but by definition the offsetTop property of an element will return the top position (in pixels) relative to the top of the offsetParent element.

So no matter how long you scroll, if the top distance between the element you are inspecting and it's parent does't change, your top value will not change.

Maybe the property you are looking for is **scrollTop**;

```
const getPos = (el) => {
    for (var lx=0, ly=0;
         el != null;
         lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.scrollTop, el = el.offsetParent);
    return { x:lx, y:ly };
}
```

Comment: Yes `scrollTop`! Yeah I'm trying to figure out what the new `y` is of the `tickers-col`. Just added it to this `lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.scrollTop, el = el.offsetParent);` testing to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code blow.

Scroll and then hover on one of the divs, you can see the y-coordinate is getting updated.

```js
const tickersCol = document.getElementById("tickers-col");


const getPos = (el) => {
  for (var lx=0, ly=0;
   el != null;
   lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.scrollTop, el = el.offsetParent);
  return { x:lx, y:ly };
}

function mouseHover() {
  const colPos = getPos(tickersCol);
  console.log('colPos', colPos)
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#tickers-col {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 120px;
  color: white;
  background: salmon;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="tickers-col">
  <ul>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">aaa</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">bbb</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ccc</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ddd</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">eee</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">fff</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">ggg</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">hhh</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">iii</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">jjj</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">kkk</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">lll</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">mmm</li>
    <li onmouseenter="mouseHover()">nnn</li>  
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: So I'm actually trying to get the y position of the `#tickers-col` it seems that the `colPos` here is the y position of the individual li? What I'm expecting is something like y:0 at the start, then when you scroll it keeps going higher since it's off screen now, so y:-200?

Comment: Ah, that makes it easier actually, I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

> After you scroll the #tickers-col how do you get the correct updated top position of the div?

`div` itself isn't moving when scrolling, instead only its direct children are moving.

So top position is :  `#ticker-col`'s `offsetTop` - `ul`'s [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) , and your js code should look like this:

```js
(function(){

var tc = document.querySelector("#tickers-col");

tc.addEventListener("scroll",function(){      
    console.log("colPos:", { x : tc.parentNode.offsetLeft,
                             y : tc.parentNode.offsetTop - tc.scrollTop,
                            });      
});



})();
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#tickers-col {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 120px;
  color: white;
  background: salmon;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id="tickers-col">
  <ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
    <li>ddd</li>
    <li>eee</li>
    <li>fff</li>
    <li>ggg</li>
    <li>hhh</li>
    <li>iii</li>
    <li>jjj</li>
    <li>kkk</li>
    <li>lll</li>
    <li>mmm</li>
    <li>nnn</li>
    <li>ooo</li>
    <li>ppp</li>
    <li>qqq</li>
    <li>rrr</li>
    <li>sss</li>
    <li>ttt</li>
    <li>uuu</li>
    <li>vvv</li>
    <li>www</li>
    <li>yyy</li>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>zzz</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

P.S.

> ```
> onmouseenter="mouseHover()"
> ```

this thing looks ugly, if you need to set the same function for some number of elements > 2 as event listener the better approach would be like so

```
var collection =
Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('mycssselector')
).forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener("myevent",/*callback*/function(){});
});
```

Comment: I ran your snippet and it's throwing errors. Could you replicate this in codepen?