# How to get the bottom right corner of a div?

Tags: javascript

i have a div of static width and height and i want to know its bottom right corner so that i can use it for top and left of another div

so basically the coordinates of the marked point in the image below,

[image]

i have tried to bottom = rect.top + rect.height;
    right = rect.top + rect.height;
i dont think above is correct. could someone help me get the bottom right corner of the div.thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the position of a div/span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288699/get-the-position-of-a-div-span-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

botRightX = rect.left + rect.width

botRightY = rect.top + rect.height

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getBoundingClientRect`. This function returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

```
document.getElementById('foo').getBoundingClientRect();
// =>  {
//       top: Number,
//       left: Number,
//       right: Number,
//       bottom: Number,
//       x: Number,
//       y: Number,
//       width: Number,
//       height: Number,
//     }
```

From there I think you can do some simple math to get the bottom right corner.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.offsetHeight` and `.offsetWidth` properties to get the height and the width of you first div. Like this:

```
var height = document.getElementById('yourDivId').offsetHeight;
```

and

```
var width = document.getElementById('yourDivId').offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const boundingRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

const bottom = div.bottom - div.top;
const right = div.right - div.left;
```

Assuming that `div` is the element you want to target.